# Calculation of Cartan structure constants

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

I'm trying to figure out the step from equation (19) to equation (20) in [this document](https://www.thephysicsmill.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/jmm_GR2_paper.pdf) when $\mathcal{F} = 0$ y $\mathcal{A} = 0$. In this case, equation (19) reduces to

$$ - e^{\alpha \phi} \hat{\omega}^{z} {}{b} \wedge e^{b} = \beta e^{\beta} \partial{\mu} \phi (d x^{\mu} \wedge d x^{4} )$$

using $\hat{e}^{z} = e^{\beta \phi} d x^{4}$ (equation (8)),

$$ e^{\alpha \phi} \hat{\omega}^{z} {}{b} \wedge e^{b} = - \beta e^{\beta} \partial{\mu} ( d x^{\mu} \wedge e^{- \beta \phi} \hat{e}^{z} ) $$
$$\hat{\omega}^{z} {}{b} \wedge e^{b} = - \beta e^{- \alpha \phi}  \partial{\mu} d x^{\mu} $$

However, I don't know how to get the equation (20)

$$ \hat{\omega}^{a z}=-\hat{\omega}^{z a}=-\beta e^{-\alpha \phi} \partial^a \phi \hat{e}^z $$

Also, I can't understand how replacing in (16) results in

$$ \hat{\omega}^{a b}=\omega^{a b}+\alpha e^{-\alpha \phi}\left(\partial^b \phi \hat{e}^a-\partial^a \phi \hat{e}^b\right) $$

Could anyone give me a suggestion or observation on how to obtain these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From (8), for $\mathcal{A} = 0$
\begin{equation}
\hat{e}^{z} = e^{\beta \phi} dx^{4}
\end{equation}
Equation (19) is
\begin{align}
-e^{\alpha \phi}\, \hat{\omega}^{z}_{b} \wedge e^{b} &= \beta e^{\beta \phi}\partial_{\mu}\phi \, dx^{\mu} \wedge dx^{4} \\
-e^{\alpha \phi}\, \hat{\omega}^{z}_{b} \wedge e^{b} &= \beta e^{\beta \phi}\partial_{b}\phi \, dx^{b} \wedge dx^{4} \\
-e^{\alpha \phi}\, \hat{\omega}^{z}_{b} \wedge e^{b} &=\beta \partial_{b} \phi \, dx^{b} \wedge \hat{e}^{z} \\
\hat{\omega}^{z}_{b} \wedge e^{b} &= -\beta e^{-\alpha \phi} \partial_{b} \phi \, dx^{b} \wedge \hat{e}^{z} \\
\hat{\omega}^{z}_{b} \wedge e^{b} &= -\beta e^{-2\alpha \phi} \partial_{b} \phi \, e^{b} \wedge \hat{e}^{z} \\
\hat{\omega}^{z}_{b} \wedge e^{b} &= \beta e^{-2\alpha \phi} \partial_{b} \phi \, \hat{e}^{z} \wedge e^{b} \\
\end{align}
This means that
\begin{align}
&\hat{\omega}^{z}_{b} = \beta e^{-2\alpha \phi} \partial_{b} \phi \,\hat{e}^{z} \\
&\hat{\omega}^{zb} = \beta e^{-\alpha \phi} \partial^{b} \phi \,\hat{e}^{z} \\
&\boxed{\hat{\omega}^{bz} = -\beta e^{-\alpha \phi} \partial^{b} \phi \,\hat{e}^{z}}
\end{align}